# Google removed app from playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services, eula

One of our apps has been removed from Playstore by Google.

//Sent by Google Play Team

**REASON FOR REMOVAL**: Violation of section 4.3 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
We classify a user’s contacts as private and confidential information. Apps which upload a user’s contacts to a service without making this clear to the user and obtaining the user’s explicit consent are regarded as being in violation of section 4.3 of the DDA.

We are getting contact information from users phone and sending the list of contacts to our server through an HTTP API. However at the server we are not storing any of those information and using only for some complex operations.

4.3 DDA agreement says we should have a separate user-agreement and opt user to agree to those Terms & Conditions.

Can we solve this problem by have a separate EULA and prompt user to agree upon those ? Please let me know the right solution because I don't want to risk my client's developer account getting deleted.

Comment: Your question appears to be focused on whether the inclusion of a seperate EULA would make your app complient with Google's terms. Questions on Stack Overflow should relate directly to some aspect of programming or software development, because your question is primarily concerned with a legal matter, it will very likely be closed as off-topic. I would suggest that in order to best answer your question, you or your client should consult your legal advisor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of a third party service.

Comment: Its not fully non-technical. Because I was not sure if the problem was with license agreement or sending/storing data securely. In had my doubts on whether I should use HTTPS while communicating this sensitive data. But it ended up that the solution is not technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can we solve this problem by have a separate EULA and prompt user to agree upon those ?*

YES..!! only this one can solve your porblem..

Comment: It didn't help me. Google suspended the app anyways... I had a seperate EULA on the welcome screen and a link to our privacy policy from the Play store.